# dependent => :destroy on table which contains two rows for 'the same result'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So I have a friendships table which looks like this:

```
  create_table "friendships", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "friend_id"
    t.integer "status"
  end
```

For each friendship created two rows are inserted, with user_id and friend_id reverted. When a user is deleted the friendship should be deleted also. This code removes one of them:

```
  has_many :friendships, :dependent => :destroy
```

But that only removes one of the friendships. In my friendship model I have this code:

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
```

I also have a custom method for removing friendships which creates a transaction that calls destroy on both the associated objects.

My solution would be to override the destroy method in User and loop through all its friendships and call my remove method on those. This works, but is it an elegant solution? I feel like there could be a nice Rails-way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please recommend a better title too. I'm sure it's called something. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most elegant solution is to have two `has_many` relations on the User model, one for 'friends of this user' (which you've already got) and one for 'users who call this user a friend'. Then set `:dependent => :destroy` on both of them:

```
def User
    # Friends of this user
    has_many :friendships, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :friends, :through => :friendships

    # Users who call this user a friend
    has_many :friendships_of, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id", :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :friends_of, :through => :friendships_of
end
```

This will mean that destroying a User also deletes any friendship records that reference that user as either the user_id or the friend_id.

Removing both the associated objects when breaking a Friendship record seems like a bad idea though - destroying a friendship doesn't usually mean that both friends cease to exist!

Comment: The user is not supposed to be destroyed. One friendship consists of two rows in the database.

Comment: Almost didn't catch that you actually got the answer right, thanks!

Comment: Ah - so do you want destroying one half of the friendship (me calling you a friend) to automatically also destroy the other half (you calling me a friend)? In that case you can implement that using a before_destroy callback method on the Friendship model.

Comment: True. has_many :friendships_of, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id", :dependent => :destroy does it too though

Comment: So you have a have_many :friendships definition on the Friendship model itself? I didn't think of that!